# Android - buildDrawingCache - makes my image black

Tags: android

I am trying to send an image to a server by converting it to a bitmap. I am using the method buildDrawingCache() but on the server side I receive my Image all dark. I have tried and read many posts about it but none helped me. Bellow my code to convert my image to bitmap:

```
    ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultValueee);
    img.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();

    img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());

    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();

    Img(imageInByte,e);
```

The Img() is responsible for sending the data. That part works ok. The XML:

```
 <ImageView
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/resultValueee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:tag="bg"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

And the PHP part:

```
<?php

$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$cnp=$_POST['cnp'];

$name=$cnp.".png";

file_put_contents('cnp/'.$name, base64_decode($base));

?>
```

What could be the motive to receive my image all dark?

Comment: Does calling img.buildDrawingCache() and img.getDrawingCache() twice messes with the resulting bmp?

Comment: Sorry..mistake of mine..I have edited my question. It's still the same.

Comment: You are still executing img.getDrawingCache(), remove Bitmap bmap... and try again, dont know maybe

Comment: One thing, better detect where is the problem, if it's client, or server or transmission. Place the resulting bitmap in anothe imageVuew just to verify the i age is created correctly. Send a static bitmap to the server and verify that the image us sent correctly. Stuff like that

Comment: Zoe..sorry for that. I resolve it. The problem was that my Image was pointing to something null. I managed to make it work. Thanks.